# Problem with lstlisting environment

Tags: environments, punctuation

I'm writing

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
      #!/bin/bash
      echo "Hello,world!"
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{frame}
```

But the output is

[image]

As shown in the picture, the exclamation mark, the *shebang*, has been converted in a dot.

How can I fix it?

The compiler used is XeLaTex.

Comment: Maybe a problem with the font you are using. Complete the snippet to a full minimal example including font settings. Which TeX compiler you are using (pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX, ...)?

Comment: As edited, the compiler used is XeLaTex

Comment: If your document is really as above, with no `document` or `frame` environments, you must get multiple errors?

Answer (score 1):

A complete minimal working example can look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
#!/bin/bash    
echo "Hello,world!"    
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This compiles fine with XeLaTeX:

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Changing from XeLaTex to LuaLaTex the problem was solved.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question... something else (weird) must be going on if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Under [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) there are some restrictions for your usage:

1. [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) inside a `frame` requires you to use a `fragile` setup:

   ```
   \begin{frame}[fragile]
   \begin{lstlisting}[..]
   ...
   \end{lstlisting}
   \end{frame}
   ```
2. You need the `frame` ending - `\end{frame}` on a line of its own *without* indentation.
3. Indentation inside a `lstlisting` environment is always interpreted literally, since listings may have to conform to some indentation rules, or just for readability purposes. So in your case I would go without any indentation.

Here's a minimal example showing the complete usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello,world!"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```